# SQL to find rows where two columns have the same value

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have `3 columns` in Oracle database having table `mytable` and i want records having `only duplicate values in 2nd and 3rd column`.

SQL> select * from mytable ;

```
column1      column2       column3

  A            50           50----required output
  A            10           20----have different values i.e. 10 and 20
  A            50           50----required output
  A            30           70----have different values i.e. 30 and 70
  B            20           20----required output
  B            40           30----have different values i.e. 40 and 30
```

I want the following output with `count(*)`:

```
 column1      column2       column3

  A            50           50
  A            50           50
  B            20           20
```

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: yes column1 is primary key and cannot be null

Comment: Primary key is unique from its definition. Here `column1` isn't unique is it mistake in example data?

Comment: @MichałPowaga sorry sorry there is no primary key

Comment: @Randy sorry sorry there is no primary key

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select column1, count (*)
from mytable
where column2 = column3
group by column1, column2;
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question it is not clear about primary key as `A` in First Column is being repeated many times.

You can try the following:

```
 select column1, column2, column3, count(*) from 
mytable where column2 = column3 group by column1, column2, column3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are sample example , i am doing this SQL Server but i am sure this query work in ORACLE also
EXAMPLE :

```
Create table #Test (colA int not null, colB int not null, colC int not null, id int not null identity) on [Primary]
GO
INSERT INTO #Test (colA,colB,colC) VALUES (1,1,1)
INSERT INTO #Test (colA,colB,colC) VALUES (1,1,1)
INSERT INTO #Test (colA,colB,colC) VALUES (1,1,1)

INSERT INTO #Test (colA,colB,colC) VALUES (1,2,3)
INSERT INTO #Test (colA,colB,colC) VALUES (1,2,3)
INSERT INTO #Test (colA,colB,colC) VALUES (1,2,3)

INSERT INTO #Test (colA,colB,colC) VALUES (4,5,6)
GO
Select * from #Test
GO

select count(colA) as tot_duplicate_count , colA ,colB ,colC  from #Test where id <=
(Select Max(id) from #Test t where #Test.colA = t.colA and
#Test.colB = t.colB and
#Test.colC = t.colC)
group by colA ,colB ,colC 
having count(colA) > 1
```

This query this total count of duplicate record per data row